# Помогите пожалуйста вывести на pdo корректно массив $user из msSQL, в массиве $user выводится только username и password, id и phone выдает null

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

case 'login':

```
if(isTheseParametersAvailable(array('username', 'password'))){
  $username = $_POST['username'];
  $password = md5($_POST['password']);

  $stmt = $db->query("SELECT id, username, email, phone FROM users WHERE username='$username' AND password='$password'");
  $stmt->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

  $stmt->execute();
  $rows = 0;
  while($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    $rows++;
  }
  if($rows==1){  


  $user = array(
  'id'=>$id, 
  'username'=>$username,
  'password'=>$password, 
  'phone'=>$phone
  );
```

Comment: Мне кажется, вы идете на преступление, не используя prepare. Поскольку username - штука уникальная,  то вызывая fetch() вы ожидаете получить лишь одну строку, или false, если совпадений не найдено. Цикл тут не нужен. Да, еще стоит определится, либо вы режим указываете при вызове fetch(), либо через setFetchMode().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php

$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = md5($_POST['password']);

$stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT id, username, email, phone FROM users WHERE username=? AND password=?");
$stmt->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$stmt->execute([$username, $password]);
  
if($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
  $user = array(
      'id'=>$row['id'], 
      'username'=>$row['username'],
      'password'=>$row['password'],
      'phone'=>$row['phone']
  );
}
```

[run PHP online](https://phpize.online/sql/mysql80/993e4cba7ab4ca9fe33feb5250357df3/php/php81/5909b3ea1c8ed41a4e4b116320f096e2/)

Comment: +1, но можно сократить: `$user = $stmt->fetch()`, и уже потом проверять значение $user.

Answer (score 0):

1. Используйте более корректный синтаксив в запросе, это вам пригоидтся)

```
$stmt = $db->query("SELECT `id`, `username`, `email`, `phone` FROM `users` WHERE `username`='".$username."' AND `password`='".$password."' ");
```

У вас в переменную $user падают не данные из БД, а данные из $_POST, поэтому вы только их и можете увидеть

Попробуйте сделать так, положите в переменную $user = $stmt->execute();

и сразу var_dump($user); Что выводится?

2. Готовьтесь получить кучу сладких комментов в сторону MD5 в пароле)

Comment: `$user = $stmt->execute()` - вы серьезно? Вы про md5 говорите, а вас не смущает тот факт, что данные из пост без подготовки в запрос попадают? И вообще, вы отвечаете или вопросы задаете?

Comment: Меня не смущает, так как отсутствие prepare() уже упомянули выше, будьте внимательнее) Вопрос тут один, с надеждой увидеть вовлеченность человека по ту сторону и всего лишь. Не все сразу магистры же, нужно найчиться дебаггингу на минималках, нужно и шишек набить) Все придет) Но человеку нужно помочь и задать вектор для плясок)

Comment: `$user = $stmt->execute()` - это и есть вектор для плясок? На мой взгляд, вы не дали ответ.